# How to get an Ogre SceneNode Axis Oriented BoundingBox?

Tags: c++, axis, bounding-box, ogre

Is there any Ogre function that allows to get the SceneNode Axis Oriented BoundingBox ?

I found :

```
SceneNode::_getWorldAABB()
MovableObject::getBoundingBox()
MovableObject::getWorldBoundingBox()
```

but it seems no one of it is the good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question the answer is no. `Ogre3D` supports only axis aligned bounding box (`AABB`).

If you need your bbox to be aligned with the object local axis, you need to implement that feature on your own.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I will code differently.